# openlayers do not show blank areas around map

Tags: dictionary, openlayers

I have a simple map. When I zoom out to the map min zoom level (whole map overview) then I see a lot blank area around the map? Is it possible not to show it? Do I need to somehow apply pan locker or set bounds or what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `restrictedExtent` attribute to restrict panning after a certain extent. Here is an example: [Openlyers restricedExtent Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/restricted-extent.html)

You can also restrict zoom levels with these attributes:

```
minZoomLevel
maxZoomLevel
numZoomLevels
```